# python drawing a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My code :

```
def izrisi_vektor(vektor):
    plt.axis([0,9,0,100])

    plt.plot(vektor,color='black')

    povprec=povprecje(vektor)
    plt.plot(povprec,color='red')

    std=standardna_deviacija(vektor)
    plt.plot(std,color='blue')

    plt.ylabel('Amplituda')
    plt.xlabel('Vzorec')
    plt.show()
    return 0
```

the vektor is a array consisting of 10 random numbers from 0 to 100
the function povprecje returns a float number witch is average of these 10 numbers. And standardna_deviacija(vektor) returns a float number of standard diviation of these numbers in arrayl. What I am trying to do is draw these on a graph.

Only one that works is the first one where I plot these array numbers.

Graph that I have at the moment

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in Python, the values are plotted on the same figure until you run "plt.show()".  From your question statement, the first plot is 10 float numbers, thus you have a nice line.  For your mean and standard deviations, they are just float numbers, which is just a point.  They are also plotted on the graph, you just cant see it because it is just one point and you are using plt.plot.  To see the trend line and 2 other points for mean and standard deviation, do:

```
plt.plot(vektor,color='black')
plt.show()

plt.scatter(1, povprec,color='red')
plt.show()

plt.scatter(1, std,color='blue')
plt.show()
```

This will output 3 plots, first one is your line as shown in your question.  The other 2 are points, with the y axis being their respective "units" (mean, standard deviation).

Comment: I tried your solution but it still didn't draw all of them. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi Isaac, are you sure there are outputs for povprec and std?  Also did you use plt.scatter?  I tried it on my Jupyter notebook and it seems to work.  There may be a bug inside your functions.  My advise would be to print out povprec and std to ensure there are numerical value outputs.

Comment: I printed them out and they are float numbers. I have not tried using plt.scatter becouse I do not know how to. Can you help me please?   Edit: My funcion looks like this now : https://imgur.com/pJK6ora and output is :https://imgur.com/Rm7nr1i and https://imgur.com/NDEBcHU

Comment: Hi Isaac, plt.scatter allows you to plot float numbers.  For plt.plot, it plots lines.  Since a float number is a point, it will not show up on a plt.plot figure.  plt.scatter allows you to plot float values as dots.  plt.scatter takes an x and y value.  You can just copy the code I provided and it should plot them.

Comment: I fixed my functions that calculate povprec and std. But now the problem is that they print in 3 difrent graphs (I want them in one) and that both povprec and std display as a point in graph not a linear line. Thank you for your anwser thoe.Edit : I have them now in 1 graph but they still display as dots where is want them to display as linear line .

Comment: To make them a linear line, use this command: plt.axhline(y=std, color='r').  in this example, I have the line at std, and the color is red.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I think I read your comment wrong, I thought you wanted a linear line.  It may be hard to draw a point on plt.plot, but you can do plt.plot([0, 0.5], [std, std]).  This will draw a very small line, but when the line is small enough, it looks like a dot.  Also, you can increase the thickness to make it look more like a dot.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing the graph only once.

Your code should be something like this:

```
x = range(0, 101)
plt.plot(x, vektor, 'black', x, povprec, 'red', x, std, 'blue')
```

This will draw all 3 lines on the same axis.

See the documentaion of [plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot) the function signature allows you to pass multiple curves to draw as:

```
 x1, y1, format, x2, y2, format2 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried your solution but it resulted in errors :https://imgur.com/QRH5CDa